# Simplifying Square Roots of a Negative Number

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I've been thinking about proving exponent laws:

By induction, we have $(ab)^n=(ab)(ab)\cdots (ab)=a^nb^n$, for any natural $n\in \mathbb{N},a,b\in \mathbb{R}$

We can extend this to any $n\in \mathbb{R}$ by the argument here:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws/Power_of_Product

but we must add the restriction that $a,b\geq 0 $ since the log of negative numbers is undefined.

Now, we often see the formula $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ for non-negative reals, which is valid by the proof given in the link. However we also see for instance here:

http://www.purplemath.com/modules/complex.htm

that $\sqrt{-9}=\sqrt{-1*9}\overset{\star}{=}\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{9}= 3i $

I don't believe equality $\star$ (the second equality above) Convince me please.

Comment: Well, when you square $3i$ what do you get?

Comment: How are you defining $\sqrt{}$ for complex numbers? The second equality does hold for the usual definitions, but the derivation would be different.

Comment: clearly $(3i)^2=3^2i^2=-9$, but I'm trying to prove it in general (also what  I just wrote involves needing to know complex multiplication commutes so its not primitive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the following definition for the $z\mapsto \mathsf{pv}\sqrt{z}$ function. First write $z=r\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}$ where $r\ge0$ and $-\pi<\theta\le\pi$.

\begin{equation}
\mathsf{pv}\sqrt{z} = \sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}
\end{equation}

where $\sqrt{r}$ is the typical square root for positive real numbers. Convince yourself that for positive real numbers $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$, then $\mathsf{pv}\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{x}$.

Then we can show:

Let $z=x+0i \in \mathbb{R}^+$, and let $w = r\mathrm{e}^{i\theta} \in \mathbb{C}$. Then

\begin{equation}
\mathsf{pv}\sqrt{zw} = \mathsf{pv}\sqrt{zr\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}} = \sqrt{zr} \mathrm{e}^{i\theta/2} = \sqrt{z} \sqrt{r}\mathrm{e}^{i\theta/2} = \mathsf{pv}\sqrt{z}\cdot\mathsf{pv}\sqrt{w}
\end{equation}

So it is true as long as one multiplicand is a positive real. I've left out some steps verifying the consistency of the definitions used. You can check those properties fairly easily.

Comment: Thank you, this gets to the heart of my question. What does the notation $pv\sqrt{z}$ mean, is it $\Re z$ ( the real part of z)?

Comment: Since complex square root is a multivalued function, it is often convenient to refer to the particular branch often selected for day-to-day use as the "principal" branch. So I use $\mathsf{pv}\sqrt{z}$ to mean "principal value" of the [complex square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value#Square_root).

It is often written as $\sqrt{z}$, but I've avoided that here because I'm using $\sqrt{x}$ as notation for the positive real square root, which is a more primitive operation.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a\,\sqrt b$ for negative numbers. For instance, 
$$
\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=\sqrt1=1,
$$
but $$ \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=i^2=-1.$$ The square root cannot be defined as a nice operation satisfying your property. There are choices to be made, and they don't behave as nicely over the complex plane.

For the particular case $a<0$, $b\geq0$ as in your equality, it just happens that $(3i)^2=-9$, so the equality holds if we adopt the convention that $\sqrt{-1}=i$.

Finally, note that always this ($\sqrt{-1}=i$) is mentioned often, it is not how mathematicians do it. What you do is to define $i$ such that $i^2=-1$, and no roots are involved.

Comment: WRONG! Consider the case where a=0 .

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer and replace "non-positive" with "non-nonnegative".

Comment: @MartinArgerami I presume you mean negative. non-nonnegative = positive, and I linked to a proof in the question that this is true for positive numbers a,b.

Comment: Nah, I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, oops. Non-nonnegative = negative. I made the correct edit. Idk what I was thinking in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Every complex number (and hence every positive real number) has two square roots. So any time you talk about "the" square root you need to be careful.

If $x$ is positive then the notation $\sqrt x$ refers to the positive square root, which is by convention "the" square root; now $\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt x\sqrt y$ for $x,y>0$, no problem.

But if $z$ is complex there's no canonical way to say which of the two square roots should count as "the" square root. So if $z$ is complex and you see the notation $\sqrt z$ you really should not read that as "the" square root, instead you need to think of it as *a* square root.

So. If $z$ and $w$ are complex is the square root of $zw$ equal to the square root of $z$ times the square root of $w$? No, just because there's no such thing as "the" square root. It *is* true for complex $z$ and $w$ that *a* square root of $z$ times *a* square root of $w$ is *a* square root of $zw$; if you read $\sqrt{}$ as "a" square root then $\sqrt{zw}=\sqrt z\sqrt w$ is true.

---

(Regarding the assertion that there's no canonical choice of "the" square root of a complex number: No, there's nothing *canonical* about the principal-value square root, that's an entirely arbitrary choice.)

Comment: I would strongly advise against reading $\sqrt{}$ as "a" square root. That's not really mathematically precise: does it mean $\forall$ or $\exists$? Unless a particular branch is specified, it's better to read it as the set of all square roots, and the notation $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ is meaningless, not true.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to answer. You make the statement that "It is true for complex z and w that a square root of z times a square root of w is a square root of zw." The crux of the question was exactly $why$ this is.....

Comment: @EvanRosica Why it is because if $a^2=z$ and $b^2=w$ then $(ab)^2=zw$.

Comment: @FengyangWang The question of whether I should read that notation as "a" square root is something we're not going to settle. Otoh I'm all for thinking of $\sqrt z$ as the set of all square roots! But in that case $\sqrt{zw}=\sqrt z\sqrt w$ is _true_ (with the usual convention that if $A$ and $B$ are sets then $AB=\{ab:a\in A, b\in B\}$).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I would still prefer to avoid the notation, but I agree that it is mathematically sound that $\sqrt{zw}=\sqrt{z}\sqrt{w}$ under the usual conventions.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit of a subtle point. Actually one should look at $\sqrt{-9}$ as the complex number whose square is $-9$. There is an ambiguity in this definition of course, because there are two numbers in $\mathbb{C}$ whose square is $-9$, namely $3i$ and $-3i$. You should note that, by the same reasoning $\sqrt{-1} \neq i$. There is a way to extend the square root to the complex plane, such that the function is continuous and even holomorphic except on some line. This function is defined as 
$$\sqrt{z} = e^{1/2 \log (z)}$$
where $\log(z)$ is some holomorphic branch(if you call it that in English) of the complex logarithm. The square of this function is the identity but the square of minus this function is also the identity, so that there is some ambiguity in the sense that there is no natural square root you can choose in $\mathbb{C}$. Note that with this definition one does not have the property 
$$\sqrt{z} \sqrt{w} = \sqrt{zw}.$$
But one does have 
$$\sqrt{z} \sqrt{w} = \pm \sqrt{zw}.$$
This is because $\sqrt{z}\sqrt{w}$ and $\sqrt{zw}$ are both solutions of $X^2 = zw$, so they are equal up to a factor -1.